# how to format jqplot yaxis as integer

Tags: javascript, label, jqplot

How can I format y axis ticks strings to be integer and not decimal.
At the moment the tickets are showing with numbers such as 076165412.654666666666 and I would like them to show as 76165412 instead.

```
  var data = [['2013/02/11',20130211],['2013/02/10',20130210],['2013/02/12',20130212],['2013/02/15',20130215],['2013/02/16',71],['2013/02/17',81],['2013/02/18',71],['2013/02/06',735],['2013/02/19',90]];

  var options = {
    title: 'Monthly statistics for EnrAll',
    autoscale:true,
    axes: {
      xaxis: {
        renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
        labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
        tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
        min:'Feb 01, 2013',
        max:'Feb 20, 2013',
        numberTicks: 15,
        tickOptions: {
          formatString:'%b %#d',
          angle: 15
        }
      },
      yaxis: {
        label: 'Count',    
        min:'0'         
      }
    },
    highlighter: {
      show: true,
      tooltipFadeSpeed: 'fast'
    }
  };
```

[image: sample graph]

Answer (score 4):

All I did to fix this one was to change the way the minimum y-axis value is specified.

Currently you have `min:'0'`, change it to `min:0` (i.e., a number rather than a string). For further insurance you could set `tickOptions` and force an integer representation, though I didn't need this myself:

```
tickOptions: {
    formatString: '%d'
}
```